# How do I check user access for given SharePoint site using power automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a requirement to write a Flow using power automate.
The requirement is to check if a user has access to given SharePoint site. Here SharePoint site address will be given as input.
I'm wondering how to achieve this using REST API in power automate.

Answer (score 0):

With REST API, you cannot check user permission directly, alternate is to use `effectiveBasePermissions` for different masks. Blog [here](http://www.lifeonplanetgroove.com/checking-user-permissions-from-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api/).

And for Power Automate, I am not sure if you can carry further steps mentioned in the blog.

Similar thread: [How to get user's permission on SharePoint site with REST API?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/199409/how-to-get-users-permission-on-sharepoint-site-with-rest-api)

The workaround I can think of will be checking if the user is in a SharePoint group. You can [get all users in a SharePoint group](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-get-users-from-a-sharepoint-group-in-ms-flow/) via REST API, and check if the user is inside of it.